# How to re-render the Redux forms while using pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to re-render sliced data and show in the form fields, I am using array.slice for slice chunks of data.

### constructor function binding handleclick function

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentPage: 1,
            todosPerPage: 3,
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
        }, () => {
                this.forceUpdate();
        });  
    }
```

### inside render function

```
 const pageNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(this.props.facilityDataInputs.length / this.state.todosPerPage); i++) {
            pageNumbers.push(i);
        }

        const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
            return (
                <li key={number}>
                     <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex', cursor : 'pointer' }}>
                    <input type="button"
                                name="facilityId"
                                value={number}
                                id={number}
                                onClick={this.handleClick}
                            />
                        </div>
                </li>
            );
        });
```

### Redux forms functions

```
facilityList = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {
        const { currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

        // Logic for displaying current todos
        const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;

let fetchFields = fields.getAll();
        let displayFetchedFields = fetchFields.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
        if (displayFetchedFields) {
            return displayFetchedFields.map((facility, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} style={{ margin: '10px 0', color: '#071F5D' }}>
                        <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                            ID:
                    <Field
                                name={`facilityData[${index}].facilityId`}
                                component='input'
                                value={this.props.facilityDataInputs[index].facilityId}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                            Ref:
                    <Field
                                name={`facilityData[${index}].facilityRef`}
                                component='input'
                                value={this.props.facilityDataInputs[index].facilityRef}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                )
            })
        }
    }
```

### render function

```
<fieldarray name ="facilitiData" component ={this facilityList}>
```

I can able to fetch slice data but, not able to re-render the forms.

Comment: Where are you using facilityList? Can you share that code?

Comment: <fieldarray name ="facilitiData" component ={this facilityList}> in the render function.. I can able to fetch slice data in console. Log but it's not reflecting in the render component

Comment: Try to use facility object to display field. You are using facilityData and props.facilityDataInputs using index. Slice will work but data will remain same on same index. Also try to update key with something more unique than index.  Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: can u please add some test code in that, I shall be thankful to you

Comment: Please its very urgent to resolve the problem

Comment: I have answered the question. Let me know if it is working.

Comment: No, I think we need to pass unique index on every click because in name field facilitydata[0].facilityRef is already set in that format when I passed as you mentioned, nothing has been displayed, can we pass custom index

example: In page no1 index would be 0,1,2 then when we click page no 2: name key index start from 3,4,5

Comment: Yes. You can try todosPerPage * currentPage + index

Comment: But with that, it doesn't re-render on state change in the backend, we need to refresh form fields as well, Actually, I am trying to do pagination,

Comment: can you edit your code in that, it would be appreciate

Comment: @JiteshManglani do you have any idea why its not re-rendering, i mean onclick i can able to change the state, but when i click on page 2 and then click on any other input then it re-render not directly clicked with that

Comment: It is rendering correct value which was problem before. Correct? What is new problem is regarding other inputs?

Comment: I can able to render, for this i need to pass update state value in the fieldarray in the form of props so that field array can be able to verify any change in the forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203973/discussion-between-madhur-and-jitesh-manglani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FieldArray doesn't recognise any change in the redux forms while slicing an array.
for this you need to pass any update props in the fieldarray

```
<fieldarray name ="facilitiData" update={this.state.currentPage} component ={this facilityList}>
```

After passing props in the fieldsArray redux forms recognise a change in the state value and it automatically re-render the component

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
facilityList = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {
            const { currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

            // Logic for displaying current todos
            const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
            const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;

    let fetchFields = fields.getAll();
            let displayFetchedFields = fetchFields.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
            if (displayFetchedFields) {
                return displayFetchedFields.map((facility, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={indexOfFirstTodo+index} style={{ margin: '10px 0', color: '#071F5D' }}>
                            <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                                ID:
                        <Field
                                    name={`facilityData[${indexOfFirstTodo+index}].facilityId`}
                                    component='input'
                                    value={this.props.facilityDataInputs[indexOfFirstTodo+index].facilityId}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                                Ref:
                        <Field
                                    name={`facilityData[${indexOfFirstTodo+index}].facilityRef`}
                                    component='input'
                                    value={this.props.facilityDataInputs[indexOfFirstTodo+index].facilityRef}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    )
                })
            }
        }
```